# Angular select value on change not updating

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

When `select` is changed, change the value to something else other than selected. I have a feature where only 4 item types can be selected at one time, if more than 4 are chosen it changes the value back to what it was before change.

The model is being updated with the correct value but the template isn't reflecting the change.

Template - i've changed from `(change)` to `(ngModelChange)` after reading [Select change event occurs before ngModel updates on angulars github.](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7971)

```
<tr *ngFor="let jobItem of job.jobItems">
    <td>
        <select 
            [disabled]="job.completed" 
            [(ngModel)]="jobItem.supplierType"
            (ngModelChange)="changeJobItemReplacementType(jobItem, $event)">
                <option *ngFor="let supplierType of supplierTypes" [ngValue]="supplierType">
                    {{ supplierType }}
                </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Event

```
changeJobItemReplacementType(jobItem: JobItem, supplierType: string) {
        // THIS IS UPDATING BUT NOT REFLECTING IN TEMPLATE
        jobItem.supplierType = jobItem.originalValues.supplierType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you post your work to https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: @TheKNVB heres a rough setup of the code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e3macv

Comment: changeJobItemReplacementType(jobItem, $event) expects two params, the second is not the change event.

Comment: @TomShaw `$event` is the new model value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with your stackblitz setup. Got it to work by adding a `setTimeout` like this:

```
changeJobItemReplacementType(jobItem: JobItem, supplierType: string) {
  console.log('changed value to: ', supplierType)
  console.log('jobItem current: ', jobItem)
  setTimeout(() => {
    jobItem.supplierType = jobItem.originalValues.supplierType;
    console.log('jobItem.supplieType modified back to original: ',jobItem)
  });
}
```